# Ajax get text file with no extension

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a bit confused about how to read an error_log with ajax. This code works only if the file error_log has an extension after it (ex .txt):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "error_log",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function (data) {
    $(".generate").html(data);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** 
error_log is protected by the server against ajax. All files work except this particular one in case you run in the same issue as me.

Comment: Check the URL this request is being sent to matches what you expect. How an extension-less URL is handled depends on how your server is configured. Try using a more complete relative path, eg `/folder/error_log`

Comment: Oh I see, it is actually a server option to block the file from being read. Thanks!

Comment: yeah...you really don't want to be exposing your error_log over HTTP - massive security hole. If for some reason you want to display info from it in a page (hopefully secured so only certain people can reach it!!) you'd need to call a PHP script which would open the file server-side and read from it, then output it to a page. If you make the file available directly via an AJAX request then it means that anyone else can also use a browser (or any other HTTP client) to fetch the data too...not a good idea.